# How can I make the C# compiler infer these type parameters automatically?

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-construction, semantics

I have some code that looks like the following. First I have some domain classes and some special comparators for them.

```
public class Fruit {
  public int Calories { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class FruitEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Fruit> {
  // ...
}

// A basket is just a group of Fruits.
public class BasketEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<Fruit>> {
  // ...
}
```

Next, I have a helper class called `ConstraintChecker`. It has a simple `BaseEquals` method that makes sure some simple base cases are considered:

```
public static class ConstraintChecker {
  public static bool BaseEquals(T lhs, T rhs) {
    bool sameObject = l == r;
    bool leftNull = l == null;
    bool rightNull = r == null;

    return sameObject && !leftNull && !rightNull;
  }
```

There's also a `SemanticEquals` method which is just a `BaseEquals` check and a comparator function that you specify.

```
  public static bool SemanticEquals<T>(
    T lhs, T rhs, Func<T, T, bool> f) {
    return BaseEquals(lhs, rhs) && f(lhs, rhs);
  }
```

And finally there's a `SemanticSequenceEquals` method which accepts two `IEnumerable<T>` instances to compare, and an IEqualityComparer instance that will get called on each pair of elements in the list via `Enumerable.SequenceEquals`.

```
  public static bool SemanticSequenceEquals<T, U, V>(U lhs,
                                                     U rhs,
                                                     V comparator)
    where U : IEnumerable<T>
    where V : IEqualityComparer<T> {
    return SemanticEquals(lhs, rhs, (l, r) => lhs.SequenceEqual(rhs, comparator));
  }
} // end of ConstraintChecker
```

The point of `SemanticSequenceEquals` is that you don't have to define two comparators whenever you want to compare both `IEnumerable<T>` and `T` instances; now you can just specify an `IEqualityComparer<T>` and it will also handle lists when you invoke `SemanticSequenceEquals`. So I could get rid of the BasketEqualityComparer class, which would be nice.

But there's a problem. The C# compiler can't figure out the types involved when you invoke SemanticSequenceEquals:

```
// Error! Compiler can't infer the type parameters.
return ConstraintChecker.SemanticSequenceEquals(lhs, rhs,
  new FruitEqualityComparer());
```

If I specify them explicitly, it works:

```
return ConstraintChecker.SemanticSequenceEquals<Fruit, IEnumerable<Fruit>,
  IEqualityComparer<Fruit>> (lhs, rhs, new FruitEqualityComparer());
```

Obviously, that's a huge hassle, and it's not very DRY. What can I change here so that I don't have to write the type parameters explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just specifying T without the U and V like this.

```
public static bool SemanticSequenceEquals<T>(
    IEnumerable<T> lhs, 
    IEnumerable<T> rhs, 
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparator)
{
    return SemanticEquals(lhs, rhs, (l, r) => lhs.SequenceEqual(rhs, comparator));
}
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? This is the most obvious solution, though I still have to specify the type parameter for `T` explicitly. It looks like the compiler can't infer T when it's a shared type parameter of two method parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You could explicitly type your arguments to SemanticSequenceEquals.  This seems to compile fine for me:

```
public static bool SemanticSequenceEquals<T>(IEnumerable<T> lhs, IEnumerable<T> rhs, IEqualityComparer<T> comparator)
{
    return SemanticEquals(lhs, rhs, (l, r) => lhs.SequenceEqual(rhs, comparator));
}

List<Fruit> a, b;
return ConstraintChecker.SemanticSequenceEquals(a, b, new FruitEqualityComparer());
```

Comment: Indeed. If you're not using the genericity, don't use generics. You don't need to have the types U and V, so you shouldn't include them. In this example, SemanticSequenceEquals does not need to know that its arguments are actually List<Fruit>, as it only uses the IEnumerable<Fruit> functionality.

Comment: You're right that `U` and `V` could be done away with; I missed this various obvious refactoring. I still seem to have to specify `T` explicitly, though. Does your example (which omits the `T` specification from the `SemanticSequenceEquals` invocation) compile for you?

Comment: It compiles fine for me in VS2010, yes.  I had to add a few `where T : class` specifiers though.